# Horizontal css list wrapping issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a css horizontal list which should not wrap itself if the container div width is lesser. For example, take a look at this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/1/

As you can see only two items : Lorem Ipsum is visible as the last few letter of Dolor could not be accommodated inside the div, so the list is wrapped. But I want everything in a line, even if some text is clipped. For example - the output I desire is 'Lorem Ipsum Dol' or whatever and rest of the text should overflow beyond the div.

I tried various combination of

```
white-space: nowrap;

display: inline-block;

float: left;
```

But could not achieve the desired result.

Note: I achieved the result using a table, but I am just curious to know what I am doing wrong here.

Edit: I guess I was not clear in my post. I have to set the table width, actually user will set the table width at run-time, I have an interface like that. And though setting ul width resolves the issue but number of items is completely dynamic. So I can't just set any width.

Comment: set width to `ul` http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/2/

Comment: you are absolutely clear with question , check the fiddle i posted in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
.LongList ul li {
display: inline-block; /* add this , remove float and its done */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/11/)

Comment: I cant see if anything added to the list in your fiddle.Your fiddle still not giving answer upto desired

Comment: well let mke check other things then

Comment: Hey, this seems to be working. Thank you :) And please do not down vote anyone. Everyone is trying to help me.

Comment: question was clear guys im sorry if im too harsh but we are supposed to read the question before jumping in with fiddles right ??? `But I want everything in a line, even if some text is clipped. For example - the output I desire is 'Lorem Ipsum Dol'` sorry again @KheemaPandey

Comment: no worries Karan I have not give you down vote, but please always calm!. thats why I removed my answer from here..

Answer (score 0):

You should use set **`overflow:hidden`** and **`display:inline-block`** to solve this issue,

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/3/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
.LongList ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 21px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

You can check this to increase **`width: 150px`** to **`250px`** in **`.LongList{}`** still **`ul`** list **`display inline block`**.

---

Another way you can archive by using **`display:inline-block`** in **`.LongList ul li{}`** class,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/12/)**</kbd>

```
.LongList ul li{
        display: inline-block;         // Add new
        float: left;                   // Remove this
 }
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: as i commented to above answer `when you extend last word it goes on next line which he does not want.`

Comment: Edited my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your fiddle and removed unnecessary rules. Check it out.

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5PBZ/6/)

```
.LongList
{
margin: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;          
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: when you extend last word it goes on next line which he does not want.

Comment: Edited my answer please check

Answer (score -1):

why have you given that width

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="160px">
```

remove this width

**and in css,give `width:auto`**

```
.LongList
    {
    margin: 0;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            height: 21px;
            width: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #fff;
            white-space: nowrap;            
            border: 2px solid #000;
    }
```

Comment: read question carefully `he desired clipped output in a container , not auto width`

Comment: Edited my answer please check